# How do I get Azure to verify a JWT on a non-Azure API

Tags: node.js, azure, jwt

I'm making a small React app and want to use Azure to log in. Everyone has an Office 365 account tied to their tenant. I've registered an app in Azure, allowed implicit flow etc., and I can log in via the React front-end. I get the token and can access basic user details via the `user.read` scope. All good.

I'm using the Msal library to do all of this, and I read somewhere that if I was getting a JWT from Microsoft Graph it would have a nonce in the header and wouldn't be usable for this type of purpose (because Graph could handle validating with each request). I double checked everything and it's calling `Msal.UserAgentApplication` with my `clientId` and the login url for our Tenant.

Now, the backend is on AWS, so what I'd like to do is have each request from the user call the API on AWS and include the token in the header.

I've tried validating the token using [azure-ad-jwt](https://github.com/dei79/node-azure-ad-jwt) and even replacing the code with someones suggestions in [this post](https://github.com/dei79/node-azure-ad-jwt/issues/14#issuecomment-461664491), but I can't get anything but an Invalid Signature.

From what I can see the code in the [those links](https://github.com/dei79/node-azure-ad-jwt/issues/14#issuecomment-461664491) basically decoded the JWT, tracks down the public keys from Microsoft, find the matching one based on the `kid`, does some tidying up of the cert, and tries to verify it. But it constantly returns:

```
{
    "name":"JsonWebTokenError",
    "message":"invalid signature"
}
```

The backend is written in Nodejs, I can't think of any more reasons why it won't work. Anyone get this working or have any ideas?

For what it's worth, I've also pasted the token into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and it decodes find, but also says Invalid Signature, though up to this point I've assumed that is because I haven't put in the public key or cert.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, just wondering if you managed to work around this situation?

Comment: I mostly got it working on an AWS Lambda function by using the JWT Decode to then compare the expiry and credentials. It's been a while, but if you let me know what part you're struggling with I can try to figure out what might help. I also recently moved the front end to use react-aad-msal on NPM, which is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, after you login through Azure SSO, you will get multiple tokens, and the only token that you need to verify is `idToken`, because its intended for you, and do not verify `accessToken`, that is intended for Microsoft Graph.

I have been trying to validation `accessToken` for days, turns out it is not for us.